# Backup software suddenly fails to backup SSD, tested on multiple software

Tags: windows-10, ssd, backup

Situation: Windows 10, system on Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB. Second disk is HDD, with enough space to clone the SSD.

Backups work flawlessly for months.
I am using two backup plans - 1) backs up everything except one large folder on c: , 2) backs up one important part of that large folder.

Few days ago, backup plan 1 stopped working. It never finishes.
When I manually shut down plan 1, plan 2 works.
I am using EaseUS Todo backup SW.

I thought it may be fault in SW, so I installed Acronis True Image 2020 trial. Similar problem. As soon as I try backing up anything (even one small directory) on c:, it never gets past analysis phase. On both tests I tried waiting for an hour+. Even better, once Acronis starts the backup process, I can't cancel it, it is canceling forever.

These are details Todo Backup writes when I try to do plan 1:

```
Checking file system on partition 4 of disk 0.
Todo Backup has checked the partition and found no problems.
Checking file system on partition 3 of disk 0 (C:\).
Todo Backup has checked the partition and found no problems.
Checking file system on partition 0 of disk 0.
Todo Backup has checked the partition and found no problems.
Backup is running, please wait patiently.
Analyzing file system on partition 4 of disk 0.
Backing up file system on partition 4 of disk 0.
Analyzing file system on partition 3 of disk 0 (C:\).
```

Checked everything with chkdsk, SSD with Samsung Magician, no problems found.
I tried doing the backup plan 1 from bootable image of Todo Backup, it failed too.

I have restored system to few days before the fail and tried backup plan 1 again. It works but "analyzing file system c:" takes about 6 minutes. Previously, it took about 10 minutes to complete the whole backup plan.
So I installed Acronis again and tried cloning the SSD. Two hours later, all I see is "computing remaining time...".

Any tips what could have gone wrong and how to fix it? I am not sure I can trust the disk or partitions. There may not be problems found by chkdsk, but something smells.

Edit: - new info

I have been scouring system logs and found something that *may* be relevant. There are multiple instances of similar errors reported in W10 Event Manager:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Ntfs" Guid="{dd70bc80-ef44-421b-8ac3-cd31da613a4e}" /> 
  <EventID>55</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-20T17:50:37.476479400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>7358</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="3868" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>PC</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="DriveName">System</Data> 
  <Data Name="DeviceName">\Device\EuFdMount\EuFdMount1</Data> 
  <Data Name="CorruptionState">0x1c</Data> 
  <Data Name="HeaderFlags">0x32</Data> 
  <Data Name="Severity">Normal</Data> 
  <Data Name="Origin">File System Driver</Data> 
  <Data Name="Verb">index item</Data> 
  <Data Name="Description">Damage in structure of indexes of filesystem found. File reference number is 0x5000000000005. File name is <cannot determine file name>. Damaged index atribut is :$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION.</Data> 
  <Data Name="Signature">0x3408c94f</Data> 
  <Data Name="Outcome">Verification of transient errors omitted due to error</Data> 
  <Data Name="SampleLength">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SampleData" /> 
  <Data Name="SourceFile">0x17</Data> 
  <Data Name="SourceLine">227</Data> 
  <Data Name="SourceTag">137</Data> 
  <Data Name="AdditionalInfo">0xd0000010</Data> 
  <Data Name="CallStack">Ntfs+0x1a8850, Ntfs+0xe8f7c, Ntfs+0xe6bd7, Ntfs+0xe40d3, Ntfs+0x15ce7a, Ntfs+0x15b24e, Ntfs+0x15b859, Ntfs+0x51e5d, ntoskrnl+0xbd645, ntoskrnl+0x12a715, ntoskrnl+0x1c86ea</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

and different type:

```
The system failed to flush data into the transaction log. The volume ID may have been corrupted: System, device name: \Device\EuFdMount\EuFdMount1.
({disk missing}
No disk in device
Insert disk into device %hs.)

- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs" Guid="{3ff37a1c-a68d-4d6e-8c9b-f79e8b16c482}" /> 
  <EventID>140</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>3</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000008</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-20T17:50:39.662791200Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>7359</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="12496" ThreadID="12552" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>PC</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-194581501-3320206473-1647570512-1001" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="VolumeId">System</Data> 
  <Data Name="DeviceName">\Device\EuFdMount\EuFdMount1</Data> 
  <Data Name="Error">0xc0000013</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Please keep in mind I had to translate the log to English.
I have no idea if those logs have any relevance on the problem, all I can tell is that they go back for months.

Comment: What was the exact `chkdsk` command you used? Have you run `sfc /scannow` yet?

Comment: I definitely didn't use sfc /scannow .
If I remember, it was basic chkdsk c:
Plus, Windows tested the disk too, through GUI, but if I remember correctly it uses chkdsk utility too.